# VBS Copy Files from a text file

Tags: arrays, text, vbscript, copy

Hiya Guys I have a text file with locations of files I'm looking for a way to read the text file and then use those locations as a source location and copy the files to a seperate destination.

I've been playing around and have seen about dynamic arrays but cant seem to understand how to put the contents of the array into variables to read as source location.

example of what I have done so far

```
Dim TxtFile

dim strDestinationFolder

strDestinationFolder = "\\SERVER\DESTLOGS"

TxtFile = "c:\windows\temp\SOFTWARELOG.txt"


Dim fso:    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim f:  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(TxtFile)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream

WScript.Echo "PSTLocation: " & f.ReadLine   ; I can read each line here in the txt file 
fso.CopyFile strDestinationFolder, f.REadline  

Loop
```

I've also tried playing with, but not sure where to start though it looks the most reliable?

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
(TxtFile, ForReading)
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine , ",")
WScript.Echo "Server: " & arrServiceList(0)
WScript.Echo "Service: " & objTextFile
For k = 1 to UBound(arrServiceList)
WScript.Echo vbTab & "Service: " & arrServiceList(i)


Next
Loop
```

Any Guidance please as to what is the best way I should go about this with vbs.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WScript.Echo "PSTLocation: " & f.ReadLine
fso.CopyFile strDestinationFolder, f.REadline
```

Your code echoes one line read from the file, and then tries to copy the destination folder to the *next* line read from the file.

If you want to do more than one thing with a line read from a file you need to assign the read line to a variable and then use that variable. Also, you need to switch the arguments of the `CopyFile` method. Source comes first, then destination. Plus, if you want the destination to be a folder, it needs a trailing backslash (otherwise you'd try to overwrite a folder with a file, which raises an error).

```
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  line = Trim(f.ReadLine)
  WScript.Echo "PSTLocation: " & line
  If fso.FileExists(line) Then fso.CopyFile line, strDestinationFolder & "\"
Loop
```

The `Trim()` accounts for spurious leading/trailing spaces in the read line, and it's always a good idea to check if a file actually exists before you try to do anything with it.

**Edit:** For detecting an existing destination file and appending a running number to the file name try something like this:

```
basename  = fso.GetBaseName(line)
extension = fso.GetExtensionName(line)

destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(strDestinationFolder, basename & "." & extension)

i = 1
Do While fso.FileExists(destinationFile)
  filename = basename & i & "." & extension
  destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(strDestinationFolder, filename)
  i = i + 1
Loop

fso.CopyFile line, destinationFile
```

Comment: Great Thanks for your help the trim line definitely helped. Very Much appreciated!!

Comment: currently it checks if the file exists is here a way to increment the name instead so if the file already exists copy same named file but add a number to the end of it?

Comment: Thanks Ansgar can you explain the logic please so that I can try understand pls? I have attempted to incorporate the above into the read my file as follows
    Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    line = Trim(f.ReadLine)
    WScript.Echo "PSTLocation: " & Line
   if Not fso.FolderExists(strDestinationFolder) Then
   fso.CreateFolder(strDestinationfolder)
   End if
 Do While fso.FileExists(destinationfile)
 filename = basename & i & "." & extension
 destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(strDestinationFolder,         filename)
 i = i + 1
 Loop
 
   fso.CopyFile line, strDestinationFolder & "\"
 
        Loop

Comment: Move folder creation outside the loop. You need to do this only once unless you want to change the destination folder midways. Also, you left out half of the code. Add `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the script. That will give you some pointers. And please don't post code in comments as that makes it unreadable.